# Running LanguageTool

Tags: java

I am trying to run `LanguageTool` in the current version 3.2 with Ubuntu 15.10. What I get with

```
java -jar /opt/LanguageTool-3.2/languagetool.jar
```

is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/languagetool/gui/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Apparently a version problem, but is the java version in the current Ubuntu really too old, or do I need to install a java alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LanguageTool version 3.2 requires Java 8 : [website](https://languagetool.org/).

Java 8 is available in the Ubuntu 15.10 repositories.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

When you only need the Java Runtime Environment :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```